# Parameters for anonymous function in strict mode

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, strict

When running this snippet

```
"use strict";
(new function test(a) { console.log(a); })(window);
```

Why do I get `undefined` for `a`? Why isn't the window passed to the anonymous function?

Comment: `new function ...` returns an object, not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is (almost) equivalent to this:

```
"use strict";

function test(a) {
  console.log(a);
}

val t = new test(undefined);

t(window);
```

Just remove the `new` keyword:

```
"use strict";
(function test(a) { console.log(a); })(window);
```